# http.trustProxy flag not recognized when deploying sails app in production mode

Tags: sails.js

I have a sails 1.0.2 app, which runs on an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS instance. Further, a reverse proxy (Apache) redirects HTTPS (443) requests from the public-side to my specified sails port (4433 in my case).

This works fine when I lift the app using `sails lift --port=4433`, the CLI states that the app is listening to port 4433 - when I visit my app from the outside via https(/:443), I can see my app.

According to sails documentation, I set up my production environment in `env/production.js` and tried deploying the app by `node app.js --prod`. So far, this also works, at least the CLI states, that the app is listening to port 4433 (like before). There is one warning: `If your app is behind a proxy or load balancer [...], you may also need to set sails.config.http.trustProxy to true.`. Well, I did that - double and triple checked, the `production.js` file has trustProxy uncommented/set to true.

Eventually, when I try accessing the site after the sails app is deployed using `--prod`, I get a `too many redirects` error in my browser.

So my question is, why is the `sails.config.http.trustProxy` flag being ignored in my production.js - or is this not the cause of the problem?

---

[Official sails.js documentation / deployment](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment)

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem, for future reference: in `staging` and `production` environments, the sails hooks/custom.js hook forwards GET requests, according to their subdomain. In my case this didn't work, because I didn't have a `www.myapp.com` domain, but something like `myapp.department.university.edu.com`.

By uncommenting this forwarding-rule [(-> here)](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate/blob/3ac16f60b4fd9cd71f481f10aad8d3dddb222239/lib/core-generators/new/templates/api/hooks/custom/index.js.template#L139-L154), everything works fine now.

So the `http.trustProxy` flag didn't have anything to do with the issue at all.

Comment: saved my day .. Thanks

Comment: Commenting these lines worked for me..... They were uncommented by default, so i commented them out and it worked.