# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when accessing my sails app with custom baseUrl

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am running my app on production mode with baseUrl defined in production.js ( baseUrl: 'http://example.net:1330')

I have made an entry in hosts file to resolve example.net to localhost.

My app starts fine on prod mode but when I access with example.net:1330/ it shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS . Goes on redirection loop .
It runs perfectly when accessed on localhost

I have set my Cors

cors: {
       allRoutes: true,
       allowOrigins: '*',
       allowCredentials: false
    },

Any suggestion what am I missing

Comment: add some code so we can diagnose the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Found the issue.Found the problem.
For future reference: in staging and production environments, the sails hooks/custom.js hook forwards GET requests, according to their subdomain. In my case this didn't work, because I didn't have a www.myapp.com domain, but something like myapp.department.university.edu.com.

detailed ans : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333236/http-trustproxy-flag-not-recognized-when-deploying-sails-app-in-production-mode

Comment: cool! Maybe add this as an answer so other can check it out if they have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please set `baseUrl` in `production.js` excluding port.

It means, if you want to serve `http://example.net:1330`, please set `baseUrl: 'http://example.net'`.

Don't set `baseUrl: 'http://example.net:1330'`

In the custom hook code, they compare `req.hostname` and `url.host` to decide whether calling redirection or not.
While [req](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).hostname cannot have port, [url.host](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/url.html#url_url_host) can have port if you set it with port.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. For future reference: in staging and production environments, the sails hooks/custom.js hook forwards GET requests, according to their subdomain.

In my case this didn't work, because I didn't have a www.myapp.com domain, but something like myapp.department.university.edu.com.

Detailed ans : [http.trustProxy flag not recognized when deploying sails app in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333236/http-trustproxy-flag-not-recognized-when-deploying-sails-app-in-production-mode)